# No module named 'basic_units'

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip

I'm trying to run the code below, but I keep getting the same error : "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'basic_units'".

```
import sympy as sym
import math
import numpy as np
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from basic_units import radians

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection': 'polar'})
ax.plot([np.pi, np.pi], [0, 10], xunits=radians)

plt.show()
```

I've seen that used in other code, but I just can't get it to work.

I was trying to make a polar plot with the angles in radians, and this seemed to be the only solution I could find, so I tried to run this test, but I encountered this error

Answer (score 0):

`basic_units` is not a python package, you should have a look for [official matplotlib document](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/units/radian_demo.html):

> Radian ticks#
>
> Plot with radians from the basic_units mockup example package.
>
> This example shows how the unit class can determine the tick locating,
> formatting and axis labeling.
>
> This example requires [basic_units.py](https://matplotlib.org/stable/_downloads/0f0fd288c7d4a6a16f4835b96343f597/basic_units.py)
>
> ```
> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
> import numpy as np
>
> from basic_units import radians, degrees, cos
> ```

You could download above source code & put in your project.

Answer (score 0):

Did you download `basic_units.py` file as numpy documentation mentions (https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/units/radian_demo.html)? If yes, you have to provide a valid path in the import statement. Now you're trying to import it as a module, but it should be a file. Like:

```
from .basic_units import radians
```

or

```
from my_code.src.basic_units import radians
```